# Photon as a wave

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, wave-particle-duality

As I was writing tutorials for a new course in waves. Then I thought about a question - is a photon a standing or a travelling wave?

I am not sure this question is well defined at all, so let me put it up differently.
An excited atom spontaneously emits a photon. We can examine two cases:

1. Let us assume a boundary condition - the potential must vanish around a sphere of radius $R$ that surrounds the atom.
2. There is no boundary or constraint on the potential.

What is the expression for the EM field in these two cases?

Thinking of this problem semiclasically - the photon is emitted and "doesn't know" about the boundary condition. Moreover, because it's a single photon -there is no interference.

I believe QFT is the right tool to use to answer this question but I am not sure about how to properly use it.

Comment: What happens in a 1D string with boundary conditions $\psi (x=0) = \psi (x=L) = 0$ when the initial condition is $\psi (x,t) = \alpha \delta (x-\frac{L}{2})$? Is the wave affected from the boundary conditions?

Comment: How fully have you checked this site (or others) for an answer to your question? This is always coming up.

Answer (score 3):

> Then I thought about a question - is a photon a standing or a travelling wave?

I am just answering the above statement/question , because it is based on a fundamental misunderstanding , continually appearing in this forum.

A photon is an elementary particle , part  of the [standard model of  particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), of mass zero, energy = $hν$ where $ν$ is  the frequency of the classical electromagnetic wave that a large number of such energy photons would create in an ensemble. [See this simple one photon at a time experiment,](https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/) to see that the footprint of a photon is a point on the screen, and the wave nature of the light shone is seen in the accumulation.

It is the [wavefunction of the photon](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169) that has sinusoidal behavior, which appears in the **probability distributions for detecting it**, as seen in the linked experiment.

A single photon is neither a standing or a traveling wave. It is an elementary particle on par with the others in the table. The standard model is the underlying level of nature from which all other theories can be shown to emerge.

For a QFT view of how [classical fields emerge](https://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html) from quantum ones see the blog here.

Comment: Really nice answer. This should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

Photons are quanta of electromagnetic field - in particular, photon creation/annihilation operators appear as the amplitude factors in the expansion of the field in the normal modes (see [quantization of EM field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Quantization_of_EM_field)). What the normal modes are depends on the boundary conditions:

- in vacuum these are often taken as plane waves, but it could be also cylindrical or spherical waves
- in a resonator or a cavity these are the corresponding resonator/cavity modes, i.e., they can be standing waves.

Answer (score 0):

A photon is a particle. It is not a wave. The properties of a photon are described in a probabilistic way by a wave. The wave is a standing or a running spherical wave, depending on the boundary conditions. By the way, a standing wave is an example of interference. There is no reason to use QFT/QED.