# How does a body "carry" kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, photons, oscillators

I have heard that photon is an oscillating electric field that carries a quanta of energy, so is there any such particle to carry macroscopic energy (such as kinetic energy, potential energy, etc)?

Comment: this is wrong  "photon is an oscillating electric field that carries a quanta of energy, " see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/662340/ ,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90646/

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy is not an process or collection of processes and has no quanta. It is a property of a process. That is to say, it is a way of consistently representing an attribute of how the process will behave and interact with other processes.

For a quantum, the kinetic energy is easily defined in the typical freshman physics way. For a multiparticle process, we can represent one consistent kinetic energy by defining an object, taking its frame, assigning an internal energy (heat etc) to account for the independent motion of the quanta, and then treating the object as a quantum with that internal energy as part of its rest mass.

In the case of photons, they are quanta, so any characteristic that describes a group of identical photons e.g. a laser will be some integer multiple of whatever characteristic a single photon has. In that case we could say the process has quantized kinetic energy, but there still aren't quanta of kinetic energy, just quanta of light that have attributes, one of them kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

Particles such as an electrons or protons can do that.  However the terms are also often used for larger objects such as tennis balls.